# Include HTML code in BootStrap Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to make use of Boot Strap Modal(http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/), I have included Bootstrap Modal Scripts and Css in my HTML and the Bootstrap Dialog works fine. Now my question is how can I include my html code in the modal dialog. 
In the examples(http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) it shows to include the HTML code in "message" property of modal. But I want to use my existing HTML in modal without rewriting the html code in JS file.

Comment: I have added my HTML code to the Message property and it shows in dialog. But I don't want to write my complete HTML code in JS file.

Comment: can you share the html and js?

Comment: Please provide your code. This is a must in order for us to give you direction

Comment: Here is my JS and CSS(https://jsfiddle.net/ura7ph8m/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the markup in a template file and

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: $('<div></div>').load('template.html')
});
```

or reuse some already existing HTML

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: $('#element').html()
});
```